# Kendo UI Dropdownlist in Grid Edit mode

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Basically I have a Kendo UI Dropdownlist as my first grid column called "instrumentName"
In popup EDIT mode, I can see the correct instrumentName in the dropdown but there's one problem when I change the value:

As soon as I select a new instrument - the instrument ID shows up on the grid (in the background). The updated INSTRUMENT NAME should appear on the grid.

And once I click UPDATE, it does NOT show the instrument NAME, but rather the instrument ID (which is a number).

Some code snippets:

```
 instrDropDown.value(e.model.instrumentId);
 nodeGrid = $("#curvesGrid").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({ ... });
      columns: [
        {
            field: "instrumentName",
            editor: instrumentsDropDownEditor, template: "#=instrumentName#"
        },
        {
            field: "instrumentTypeName"      
        },
        edit: function(e){
            var instrDropDown = $('#instrumentName').data("kendoDropDownList"); 
            instrDropDown.list.width(350);  // widen the INSTRUMENT dropdown list
            if (!e.model.isNew()) {
                instrDropDown.value(e.model.instrumentId);
            }
        }
  });
```

and here's my template editor for that Dropdown :

```
function instrumentsDropDownEditor(container, options) {

    // INIT INSTRUMENT DROPDOWN !
    var dropDown = $('<input id="instrumentName" name="instrumentName">'); 
    dropDown.appendTo(container);
    dropDown.kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "id",
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: "/api/breeze/GetInstruments"
            },
        },
        pageSize: 6,
        //select: onSelect,
        change: function () { },
        close: function (e) {

        },
        optionLabel: "Choose an instrument"
    }).appendTo(container);
}
```

Do I need to do anything special on change of the Dropdown ?

thanks.
Bob

Answer (score 0):

`dataFieldValue` is what is going to be saved as *value* of the `DropDownList`. If you want `name` to be saved then you should define `dataValueField` as `name`.

Regarding the background update that's the default behavior since this is an ObservableObject and as consequence changes are automatically propagated. If you don't want this you should probably try using a *fake* variable for the drop-down and in the `save` event copy it to the actual field. Do you really need this?